# Change Text in EditText when pressing the EditText

Tags: android, android-widget

Some EditText (Like when you write a text message) can be clicked and opened, so you can change the text inside the EditText. It also gives you the keyboard so you can write, etc.

How do I achieve the same thing?

Currently I got this:

```
public void onDescriptionBoxClick(View view) {
    EditText et = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);


}
```

And I don't know what to do other than that.

Do I have to call the keyboard forth so the user can edit the text in the box?

Comment: ever heard of EditText ?

Comment: That is what I mean actually...brainfart..

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit text using a `TextView`. to accomplish what you want you have to replace the `TextView` with a `EditText` widget. and then replace it with the `TextView` containing the text entered in the `EditText`.

You can accomplish this in a few ways:

1. Using Fragment, more compicated.
2. You can use simple `TextView` and `EditText` widgets and set their `Visability` accordingly.

Comment: I am not getting you question, when you press on the EditText the keyboard pops up and you can edit it.... what are you trying to achive?

Comment: It does that automatically..? Okay didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

I would place an EditText element right next to your textView which has the attribute android:visibilty="gone"

then in your code:

```
public void onDescriptionBoxClick(View view) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    EditText et = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    et.setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: So tell us, what you are trying to do. When clicking (and thereby focusing) on an EditText the keyboard should be opened automatically by the android system.